# concurrentLinkedQueue offer/poll blocking

Tags: java, multithreading

does offer blocks poll or vice versa  ? meaning , can a producer offer and at the same time a consumer trying to poll ?  or if a producer was offering , the queue blocks till he is done ?

object A

```
  while (true){
    inputQueue.offer(newPartList);
}
```

object B

```
     while (true){
    inputQueue.poll(newPartList);
}
```

Comment: Why poll like this in a spin loop, instead of just calling`take()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not. use [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) instead. Remember to use methods from [BlockingDequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) or [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interfaces to get values. as these methods are implemented as blocking.

**Update**

Neither `offer` nor `poll` methods are blocking. In linked interfaces only `put*` and `take*` methods are implemented as blocking. `put` blocks as long as the queue is full, `take` blocks if the queue is empty.

Now I see You are asking something else.
In [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)  calling `offer` blocks `poll`, because this implementation has inernal `Lock` for synchronizing access. In [ConcurrentLinkedQueue's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) JavaDoc it is explicitly stated, that:

`This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm based on one described in`[Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf)`by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott.`

which suggests that these operations don't block each other. If You are interested, I strongly suggest reading that paper for more insight.

Comment: "No, it does not" block ?

Comment: it seems that , the poll/offer is truly not blocking , but as... the list size increase , the time taken to offer/poll increases

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean "thread A/B" when you say "object A/B".

Neither poll() nor offer() is a blocking method (Read the documentation for the Queue interface).

I don't understand the `while(true)` loops in your example, but you appear to be asking what happens when you have an empty queue, and a *data race* between thread A, which calls q.offer(), and thread B, which calls q.poll().

Since you are asking about a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, the answer is simple:  ConcurrentLinkedQueue is inherently thread-safe, which means there can be only two possible outcomes.  Either thread A wins the race (i.e., the offer() "happens before" the poll()), or thread B wins the race (the poll() "happens before" the offer()).

```
There is no such thing as "at the same time."  In the case of ConcurrentLinkedQueue,
"thread safe" means that no matter how close the race, there will always be a winner
and a loser.
```

So, if A wins (the offer() happens before the poll()), then thread B will get the datum from the queue, and the queue will be left empty.  If B wins (the poll() happens before the offer()), then thread B will get null (Again, read the doc for the Queue interface), and the datum will be left sitting in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

It is not as simple as it seems to be. Actually acording to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`'s javadoc, it follows a non-blocking algorithm:

> "This implementation employs an efficient non-blocking algorithm based on one described in Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott."

If you are curious enough and have a look at the source code, you'll see something like this:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue.
 * As the queue is unbounded, this method will never return {@code false}.
 *
 * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Queue#offer})
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 */
public boolean offer(E e) {
    checkNotNull(e);
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

    for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
        Node<E> q = p.next;
        if (q == null) {
            // p is last node
            if (p.casNext(null, newNode)) {
                // Successful CAS is the linearization point
                // for e to become an element of this queue,
                // and for newNode to become "live".
                if (p != t) // hop two nodes at a time
                    casTail(t, newNode);  // Failure is OK.
                return true;
            }
            // Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next
        }
        else if (p == q)
            // We have fallen off list.  If tail is unchanged, it
            // will also be off-list, in which case we need to
            // jump to head, from which all live nodes are always
            // reachable.  Else the new tail is a better bet.
            p = (t != (t = tail)) ? t : head;
        else
            // Check for tail updates after two hops.
            p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
    }
}
```

The comments from the source code suggest a rather try-error aproach than a secured-synchronized one.

Comment: What a terrible idea to use `p` and `q` in the same code.