# Best way to handle asymmetric offer and poll doing on a sized BlockingQueue

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, queue

There's a BlockingQueue (ArrayBlockingQueue in particular) which is accessed by the same number of threads `offer` and `poll` to/from that (5 threads are offering and 5 other threads are polling).

```
BlockingQueue myQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
```

The problem is that if say the `offer` frequency is every 1 ms, the `poll` frequency would be something near every 1500 ms (Because of processing time consumed by each polled object, in each loop interval). Having this situation, The Queue gets filled causing the new `offer` commands to fail and objects get dropped.

```
while (true) {
    Object obj = myQueue.poll();
    if (obj != null) {
        // Process the object, takes ~ 1500 ms
    }
}
```

What's the best approach (performance-oriented) to get this to work?

- Should I increase the number of `poll`ing threads by x1500?
- Maybe increasing the size of ArrayBlockingQueue or even replacing it with a ConcurrentLinkedQueue would be the solution?
- Or just increasing the TimeOut in `offer(TimeOut, TimeUnit)` method in `offer` threads would relieve the issue?
- Or a better way?....

It's important to note that the incoming `offer`ed objects are unstoppable, so objects shouldn't be accumulated in the queue. In conclusion, **Speed** and **Performance** are vital to prevent collapsing in this data stream.

Thanks

Comment: Why poll at all? It's a blocking queue: block.

Comment: @user207421 Do you mean `poll` method blocks the queue to the `offer` while polling? If so, Apparently here stated the contrary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23056822/190929

Comment: No it doesn't, and I haven't stated otherwise, and it would be useless if it did, but [take()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()) blocks while the queue is empty, which is rather more useful.

Comment: So items come in at 1 ms intervals, and it takes 1500 ms to process each item? You're not going to solve that problem by adding 1500 threads on a single computer. It's also unlikely that you can reduce the per-item processing time to something less than 1 ms. My first question is whether you're really getting 1000 items per second on input. And why?